# How can I invoke gnuplot through a Windows Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, gnuplot

I want to invoke `gnuplot` with a Windows batch file (ultimately to be built by perl).

I wrote a minimal batch file:

```bash
cd \progra~1\gnuplot\bin
gnuplot
plot sin(x)
```

It indeed brings up the gnuplot window, with the `gnuplot>` prompt, but does not show the last line or an error message.

If I `exit`, I then get the system error message:

```
'plot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So it seems the `gnuplot` command is not getting to the gnuplot interpreter, but is being handled by the system command window.

How can I get the `gnuplot` commands to gnuplot?

Comment: First, I have no idea why you'd feel the need to resort to DOS 8.3 format in modern Windows. I cannot therefore guess which location within the root of the drive of your current working directory you have placed your portable executable. Note that I said executable, because it is an executable file, not a command. I would however ask that you try this one liner, replacing my guessed location, (if it is not really in `\Program Files`), and ensuring that the executable file really has an `.exe` extension. ```@(Echo plot sin(x^)) | "%ProgramFiles%\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe"```.

Comment: I had no problem getting to gnuplot. You will notice that gnuplot WAS invoked by the batch file, and showed its prompt and did execute commands entered at the terminal. The problem is that the subsequent batch commands intended for gnuplot didn't get there.

Comment: I never said you did, neither did I fail to notice anything. Instead of commenting just to argue, how about you run the command line I offered.

Comment: The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` processing a batch file executes one command line after the other. For more details see [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) In other words `cmd.exe` opens the batch file, reads the first line, parses it, finds out that no more line must be read from the batch file, remembers current offset in batch file, closes the batch file, executes the command line. After executed command finished, `cmd` opens again the batch file, seeks to remember position in batch file, reads next line

Comment: parses this command line, finds out that no more line must be read from the batch file, remembers current offset in batch file, closes the batch file and executes the command line which is in your case the execution of the program or script `gnuplot`. Now `cmd` waits for self-termination of the program (or the executable interpreting the script). There are no more lines read from the batch file until the started executable terminates itself. That is the meaning of the word __batch__ – one command/executable executed after the other, no parallel processing.

Comment: `cmd` cannot know magically that it despite `gnuplot` is running it should read the next line from the batch file which is `plot sin(x)` and send that string to the standard input stream of `gnuplot`. On the other hand `gnuplot` is not aware of being started by `cmd.exe` using the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) because of a command line in a batch file and that the command to execute by `gnuplot` should not be read from standard input stream but from the batch file.

Comment: It could work using as first line `cd /D "%ProgramFiles%\gnuplot\bin"` or `cd /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\gnuplot\bin"` and as second line `echo plot sin(x)| gnuplot.exe` which instructs `cmd.exe` to change first the current directory and if necessary also the current drive to the `bin` subdirectory of the program files directory of `gnuplot`, start `gnuplot.exe` and output next `plot sin(x)` to standard output stream of `cmd.exe` process with the instruction to redirect that output to standard input stream of running `gnuplot.exe` because of the redirection operator `|`.

Comment: However, the author of `gnuplot` thought about using this executables from scripts or other executables and offers several command-line options for running it without user interactions. It is __always__ highly recommended reading first the documentation / manual / usage help of an executable __before__ using it, especially on using it scripted from within a script file like a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

In the gnuplot console check `help command-line-options`. Option `-p` for persist and `-e` for execute single command line.

What about someting like this:

```
c:\progra~1\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe -p -e "plot sin(x)"
```

Comment: @user1067305 If it solved your issue, please accept the answer indicating that the question is answered.

Comment: @user1067305 if you need more commands you have to separate them by semicolons, e.g. `gnuplot -p -e "set xrange[-1:1]; set yrange[-1:1]; plot sin(x)"`.

Comment: or use gnuplot -p -e "load 'plotfile'" Note: this only shows the graph, no command window opens.

Comment: @helper yes, with this you could create a complex multiline plot file. You could do it even shorter `gnuplot -p -c "plotfile"`.

Comment: @user1067305 If it solved your issue, please accept the answer indicating that the question is answered. That's how StackOverflow is supposed to work.